# Is std::less supposed to allow comparison of unrelated pointers at compile-time?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std, compile-time

Consider this code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
inline constexpr const void *foo = &typeid(T);

int main()
{
    constexpr bool a = std::less<const void*>{}(foo<int>, foo<float>);
}
```

<kbd>[Run on gcc.gotbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:47,endLineNumber:5,positionColumn:47,positionLineNumber:5,selectionStartColumn:47,selectionStartLineNumber:5,startColumn:47,startLineNumber:5),source:%27%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctypeinfo%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Ainline+constexpr+const+void+*foo+%3D+%26typeid(T)%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++constexpr+bool+a+%3D+std::less%3Cconst+void*%3E%7B%7D(foo%3Cint%3E,+foo%3Cfloat%3E)%3B%0A%7D+%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:52.17506098630851,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1000,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:13,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+10.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:45.04027643353199,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:10,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%232+with+x86-64+clang+10.0.0%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:47.8249390136915,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)</kbd>

If I use `<` instead of `std::less` here, the code doesn't compile. This is not surprising, because the result of a relational pointer comparsion is [unspecified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Pointer_comparison_operators) if the pointers point to unrelated objects, and apparently such a comparsion can't be done at compile-time.

> ```
> <source>:9:20: error: constexpr variable 'a' must be initialized by a constant expression
>     constexpr bool a = foo<int> < foo<float>;
>                    ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> <source>:9:33: note: comparison has unspecified value
>     constexpr bool a = foo<int> < foo<float>;
>                                 ^
> ```

The code still doesn't compile, even if I use `std::less`. The compiler error is the same. `std::less` appears to be implemented as `<` in at least libstdc++ and libc++; I get the same results on GCC, Clang, and MSVC.

However, the cppreference page about [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) claims that:

1. Its `operator()` is `constexpr`.
2. It magically implements strict total order on pointers, i.e. can be used to compare unrelated pointers with sensible results.

So, is it a bug in all those compilers, or am I missing some detail about `std::less` that makes the code above ill-formed?

Comment: Off-topic: Converting both pointers to uintptr_t before comparison doesn't appear *'magical'* to me...

Comment: @Aconcagua If it does that, then there is no way for it to be `constexpr`.

Comment: Found [another relevant paragraph in cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_objects) (at the end of the section).

Comment: If you don't use `a`, it can simply be optimised away. What happens if you use it? For instance, with `return a ? 99 : 101 ;`

Comment: @TonyK The code doesn't compile even if the variable is not used, so I doubt it would compile if I used it somehow.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. I got as far as "If I use `<` instead of `std::less` here, the code doesn't compile" and assumed that if you use `std::less` the code does compile.

Comment: Actually MSVC compiles your example. But `std::less` output is not useful: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/b54xzn4v7

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't think there's a clear answer to the question that you're asking. This is a specific case of [LWG 2833](https://wg21.link/LWG2833): marking a library function `constexpr` does not explain the circumstances under which calling the function will yield a constant expression.

Until this issue is resolved, I think you simply cannot rely on `std::less` being able to compare unrelated pointers at compile time.

Answer (score 7):

To be valid `constexpr` function, it should have parameters for which the result is `constexpr`, not necessary all parameters.

For example

```
constexpr int foo(bool b) { if (!b) throw 42; return 42; }
```

is valid, `f(true)` can be used in constexpr (even if `f(false)` cannot).

```
constexpr int a[2]{};
constexpr bool b = std::less<const void*>{}(&a[0], &a[1]);
```

is valid and is enough to allow `less::operator()` to be `constexpr`.

I don't think it is specified which ranges/values are correct for constexpr in standard.

So all compilers are correct.

Comment: How does that apply to this specific question?

Comment: @＿Static＿assert: Probably nitpicking, but function marked as `constexpr` (with constant arguments) is not sufficient to be used in constant expression in general.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you declare a variable like `constexpr bool a = std::less<const void*>{}(foo<int>, foo<float>);`, a constexpr variable is required to satisfy the following rule:

> A constexpr specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as const. Such an object shall have literal type and shall be initialized. In any constexpr variable declaration, the full-expression of the initialization shall be a **constant expression**. (Note the emphasized part)

a constant expression must be a core constant expression, hence it must satisfy the core constant expression rules:

> a **relational** or equality operator where the result is **unspecified**;

In your code, `&typeid(int)` and `&typeid(float)` is unspecified due to:

> Comparing unequal pointers to objects is defined as follows:
>
> > - If two pointers point to different elements of the same array, or to subobjects thereof, the pointer to the element with the higher subscript compares greater.
> > - If two pointers point to different non-static data members of the same object, or to subobjects of such members, recursively, the pointer to the later declared member compares greater provided the two members have the same access control and provided their class is not a union.
> > - **Otherwise, neither pointer compares greater than the other**.

`&typeid(int)` and `&typeid(float)` conform with the third bullet point.  And

> If two operands p and q compare equal, p<=q and p>=q both yield true and pq both yield false. Otherwise, if a pointer p compares greater than a pointer q, p>=q, p>q, q<=p, and q<p all yield true and p<=q, p<q, q>=p, and q>p all yield false. **Otherwise, the result of each of the operators is unspecified**.

So, the result of comparing `&typeid(int)` with `&typeid(float)` is unspecified, Hence it's not a constant expression.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Modfied my answers.

Comment: Yep, now it looks like a correct explanation of why `<` doesn't work at compile-time in this case. But still, it's unclear if `less` should've been implemented using some compiler magic instead of `<` to make it work at compile-time even for unrelated pointers. (According to Brian's answer, the standard doesn't specify if it should or not.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat As far as I know, it can't because the entire `typeid` is implementation-defined  and if the operand is of polymorphic class type, it would be a runtime value.